# pgAdmin 4 is stuck in one page. How can solve this problem?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-15

I have tried to install postgresql multiple times. My environment is Window 11 and the postgresql version is 15.3 winx86-64. The installation completed but when I run pgadmin, it just stuck in one page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW3vJ.jpg)

Is there any solution for this problem ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to downgrade to pgAdmin 4 v7.3 until this issue has been fixed, as everyone is currently experiencing this problem with this version.

You can follow this link to download
[pgAdmin download link](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/)